# Should solicitation of models/subjects be explicitly listed on the FAQ?

Tags: discussion

I've just flagged a post where someone is basically asking for people to model for his art project. This isn't specifically mentioned in the FAQ though to me that it is pretty clearly a "polling" type question and those are explicitly listed as things not to discuss.

Should the FAQ be updated with an explicit prohibition of solicitation (of models, photogs, etc.)? Maybe list some of the popular sites that already exist for this, e.g. Model Mayhem.

Answer (score 4):

Actually it's a larger class of questions that we would want to avoid here - where the point of question is not getting the *answer*, but getting some *action*. That would also include requests like

- Will one of you guys be my wedding photographer?
- Please fix the colors on this photo
- Has anybody got Acme 70-200 f/4.0 for sale?

These are all answerable practical questions based on a real-life problem as requested in FAQ, and even have a single correct answer, but not what the format is meant for.

But looks like "too localized" would be a good reason to close them; and that possibility is already covered in FAQ. True, it's under a section you might read after your question gets closed, not under the one that you might read before asking; so there might be some merit in having a short notice in FAQ that this is not the place to ask for participation in photography-related activities.

Comment: OK. I don't see what's wrong with spelling it out, though. It could be a simple bullet point added to the first item ("what is it NOT about"). At least that's on the first screen of the FAQ and therefore increases the likelihood that people will read it. It doesn't really matter what the reason for close is; it just seems to make sense to explicitly say something to the effect of, "this is not the place to find a model for your shoot".

Comment: Mostly, because specifically *looking for models* happens so rarely. You'd make all the people who *do* care about the site and who *do* seem to get it naturally read the information that is meant for a fly-by who most likely won't bother with FAQ in first place. I think a short notice about the whole class of *requests* would be enough, but listing all specific rare occasions would be just noise. Each sentence making the first page of FAQ longer is *reducing* likelihood people will read it (TL;DR).

Comment: @djangodude - Generally the FAQ is the *frequently* asked stuff (hence the F in it).  If we try make it cover every case then its far too daunting.

Comment: OK, thanks. It's first day on the Internet and all... :-/